# Search in Android offline docs

Tags: android

The offline docs that I use include Android Docs up to `API 21`. I can open offline docs in browsers. For example this is address of `Package Index - Android SDK` :

```
file:///path/to/android-sdk-linux/docs/reference/packages.html
```

But when I search by any keyword, it does not found any thing! How I can solve this problem?

I know I can find any thing by consuming sufficient time, but it is expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is an error on chrome dev tools when I search the content.

> /* callback */google.search.WebSearch.RawCompletion('1', null, 403,
>   'The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to
>   the Google Custom Search API
>   (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)', 200)

[image]

It seems that the api to support this has been broken.

Comment: What is the typical usage do you have?  If you want to search by class name, you could just go to docs/reference/classes.html.

Comment: Also I want to find related topics in `API guides`, `Training` and other. I know I can find any thing by consuming sufficient time, but it is expensive.